# cannot able to add my custom domain through the settings in appwrite console

Tags: appdomain, appwrite

I have installed the Appwrite on a docker container and when I try to add my custom domain from settings I get server error.
Does anybody know what is going on or am i missing something here?

i was able to see the logs and it says
Unreachable CNAME target (--.--.--.--), please use a domain with a public suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your main appwrite domain by setting the `_APP_DOMAIN` and `_APP_DOMAIN_TARGET` [environment variables](https://appwrite.io/docs/environment-variables#general)? The [Custom Domain](https://appwrite.io/docs/custom-domains) setting in the Appwrite Console is for project-specific domains usually for when your app needs 1st party cookies.